# Как бы звучало по-русски название медведя *r̥ḱs-os/*r̥ḱt-os, доживи оно до наших дней?

Tags: этимология, история-языка

Как известно, слово "медведь" это слово-заменитель табуированного "истинного" имени зверя. Похоже что такие замены происходили неоднократно - старое "истинное" имя забывалось и табу переходило на новое имя и так далее.

Но если бы это имя не было табу, как бы оно звучало сегодня?

За прошедшие тысячелетия слова теряли окончания, менялись гласные и т.д. как бы сегодня звучало слово *r̥ḱs-os/*r̥ḱt-os ?

Comment: кстати есть гипотеза что и "изначальное" прото-индоевропейское слово для медведя - это тоже заменитель табуированного - что-то типа разрушитель - всё-таки мишка зверь суровый.

Comment: Ну да, я даже уверен что так оно и есть на самом деле, просто дальше сложно проследить. Вроде даже когда-то хотел задать вопрос про более глубокие замены, но он совершенно в Russian.SE не вписывается.

Comment: @shabunc:
А есть ли какие-то основания считать, что это именно эвфемизм, а не просто индоевропейская этимология?  В случае с германским и славянским эвфемизмами у нас налицо общеиндоевропейский корень.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Очень интересный вопрос, давайте прикинем.

**I.** Сначала рассмотрим переход индоевропейских фонем в праславянские в варианте ***r̥ḱt-os**.

Поскольку славянские языки – это языки "satem", то ***ḱ** > ***s**.

Окончание ***ŏs** > ***ŭs**

***r̥** > ***ăr** или ***ŏr**

Получаем раннепраславянское ***ărstŭs** / ***ŏrstŭs**.

Далее начал действовать закон открытых слогов и возрастающей звучности слога, конечный ***s** отпал, чтобы открыть конечный слог, и тогда сразу же ***ŭ** > ***ъ** (***ărstъ** / ***ŏrstъ**). Начальные сочетания гласного с плавным перед согласным перераспределились с удлинением гласного: ***ărstъ** / ***ŏrstъ** > ***rāstъ** / ***rōstъ**, а долгие ***ā** и ***ō** слились в один звук **а**. Таким образом, к концу праславянской эпохи мы имеем ***rastъ**, что, в принципе, означает, что старославянская форма будет ***растъ**. Русское соответствие этой форме однозначно определить невозможно, поскольку мы не знаем, какое ударение было в этой форме. Если ударение было восходящее, то получилось бы русское ***раст** (как стсл. **рало** ~ рус. **рало**), а если нисходящее, то было бы ***рост** (как стсл. **равьнъ** ~ рус. **ровный**).

То есть, для варианта ***r̥ḱt-os** у нас получается русское ***раст** / ***рост**.

**II.** Для варианта ***r̥ḱs-os** всё происходило бы точно так же, за тем исключением, что мы бы получили раннепраславянское ***rassъ**, но закон открытых слогов и возрастающей звучности слога не допускал существования слога ***ssъ**, поскольку два равных по звучности согласных не могли стоять рядом. Два одинаковых фрикативных согласных сливались в один, этот слог упростился в ***sъ**, дав ***rasъ** ~ стсл. ***расъ** ~ рус. ***рас** / ***рос**.

**Выводы**: Поскольку мы не обладаем абсолютно полной информацией, и поскольку мы лишь строим предположения, то к однозначному ответу прийти невозможно, тем более что даже протоиндоевропейский архетип неоднозначен. Тем не менее, определённые выводы можно сделать. Это слово бы звучало одним из четырёх способов:

> ***раст** / ***рост** : ***рас** / ***рос**

---

**In English**

It is a very interesting question, let us investigate into it.

**I.** First, let us consider the change of the PIE phonemes into the Protoslavic ones for the ***r̥ḱt-os** variant.

Since the Slavic languages are "satem" languages, then ***ḱ** > ***s**.

Ending ***ŏs** > ***ŭs**

***r̥** > ***ăr** or ***ŏr**

So, we get the Early Protoslavic ***ărstŭs** / ***ŏrstŭs**.

Then the law of the open syllables and the increasing sonority of the syllable came into action, the final ***s** disappeared, and ***ŭ** > ***ъ** (***ărstъ** / ***ŏrstъ**). The initial vowel plus a liquid before a consonant combinations got rearranged and the vowel lengthened: ***ărstъ** / ***ŏrstъ** > ***rāstъ** / ***rōstъ**, and the long ***ā** and ***ō** merged into the single sound **а**. So, at the end of the Protoslavic epoch we have ***rastъ**, which actually means that the Old Church Slavic form would be ***растъ**. One cannot define a single Russian correspondence to this OCS form, since we do not know what tone it had. If the tone was rising, we would get Russian ***раст** (like OCS. **рало** ~ Rus. **рало**), but if it was falling, we would get ***рост** (like OCS. **равьнъ** ~ Rus. **ровный**).

That means that for ***r̥ḱt-os** we would have Russian ***раст** / ***рост**.

**II.** For the ***r̥ḱs-os** variant everything would be just the same way, only we would get Early Protoslavic ***rassъ**, but the law of the open syllables and the increasing sonority of the syllable did not allow such syllables as ***ssъ**, since two consonants of equal sonority could not stand together. Two fricative consonants merged, this syllable would get simplified into ***sъ**, giving ***rasъ** ~ OCS. ***расъ** ~ Rus. ***рас** / ***рос**.

**Summary**: Since we do not possess absolutely full information, and since we just make an assumption, we cannot come to the single correct answer. Nevertheless, we can make some conclusions. In Modern Russian this word would be one of the four:

> ***раст** / ***рост** : ***рас** / ***рос**

Comment: *+ḱt* is usually considered an example of a such called thorn cluster (from its initial reconstruction by Brugmann), a result of a metathesis from earlier dental-velar combination *+tḱ*. In most post-Anatolian IE languages one of the consonants is lost from these clusters, including Russian *земля* < *+dʰǵʰom-*. Why do you think the cluster would persist as is in this case?

Comment: @Quassnoi - Why did it persist in Greek?.. Who knows. Anyhow, if _t_ had been lost, the result would have been exactly as the second pair, _*рас / *рос_. As for the possibility of loosing the first element of the cluster, _ḱ > s_, you haven't considered it either. )))

Answer (score 4):

We can only reconstruct the PIE word through methods of comparative linguistics (comparing the similar words in the related language and trying to figure out their common source, which, being applied the sound changes relevant for the appropriate languages, would yield the attested words).

In particular, the reconstructed word for "bear" is derived from 5 attested words from Latin, Ancient Greek, Sanskrit, Old Irish and Hittite.

Sound changes are not the only factor which defines the language development: metonymy, loaning, folk etymology, morphological transformations etc. all can contribute, and, unlike the sound changes, none of them can be predicted.

This way, we can only hypothesize about "what would the word look like, should it be only affected by the sound changes and nothing else".

Thus said, we can apply the following laws:

- Post-Anatolian: initial laryngeal is lost, **tk* is changed to a thorn cluster: **h₂ŕ̥tḱos* > **ŕ̥ḱtos*
- Proto-Slavic: the second part of the thorn cluster is dropped, **ŕ̥* becomes **ьr/ъr*, **ḱ* becomes **s*, **-os* becomes **-ъ*: **ŕ̥ḱtos* > **ъrsъ/ьrsъ*. However, since the reduced vowel could not start a word, either a metathesis would occur or a prosthetic sound would be added to the beginning of the word: **jьrsъ / *vъrsъ / *rъsъ / *rьsъ*
- Russian: the first reduced (in strong position) becomes **о* or **е*, the second one (in weak position) falls:

  - **jьrsъ* > **ерс*
  - **vъrsъ* > **ворс*
  - **rъsъ* > **рос*
  - **rьsъ* > **рес*

Again, those are just wild hypotheses, as we all know the actual Russian word for "bear" has nothing to do with any of them.

Comment: *ŕ̥ **does not** become Protoslavic *rъ.

Comment: @YellowSky: Watkins thinks it does. I used the table in the appendix to his "The American Heritage Dictionary of Indo-European Roots".

Comment: Could you please quote a couple of examples he gives?

Comment: @YellowSky: you're right, the table was referring to OCS, not Proto-Slavic.

Answer (score 0):

ПИЕ форма: ***a̯rtcos*** (после r идет t)

Это дало бы что-то вроде ересь/ерсь.

Comment: Why the palatalized **сь**?

Comment: @YellowSky Трубачев считает, что в слав. это было бы _*ръsь_.

Comment: @jwalker - Probably _*rъsь_, not _*ръsь_? Anyhow, I'd be grateful if you provide a detailed reference to that.

Comment: @YellowSky Да, _*rъsь_, прошу прощения. Этимологический словарь славянских языков под ред. Трубачева, выпуск 18, стр. 66.

Comment: @jwalker - But what is the linguistic reason for **сь** being palatalised? Trubachev writes there that _*rъsь_ 'bear' merged with the Russian _рысь_ 'lynx', but Vasmer vol. 3, p. 530 writes that _рысь_ is the original Slavic reflex of the IE _*lysь_ 'lynx' merged with _рыжий_, _русый_, _рык_ to form _*rysь_. What I mean is there's no agreement on this point among the major scholars, and as for me, I'd rather believe Vasmer than Trubachev.

Comment: @YellowSky Sorry, I'm just a messenger here. But I'd like to know why you prefer Vasmer over Trubachev.

Comment: @jwalker - Just because I can't see the reason for the Trubachev's palatalized **сь**, and because I use Vasmer for years and I always find his etymologies sensible.

Comment: @Anixx Действительно что-то вроде "ересь", но в другом смысле.

Answer (score -1):

Тут важно уточнить, к какому времени и ареалу относится слово, восходящее к протоиндоевропейскому [h₂ŕ̥tḱos](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/h%E2%82%82%C5%95%CC%A5t%E1%B8%B1os). С течением времени названия одних животных переходят на других (например, слова "берлога" как "логово бера" и "бирюк" восходят к одной основе, но "бирюком" чаще называют волка-одиночку, чем медведя; также восходят к общей протооснове, например, и слова "бык" и "пчела", хотя это разные животные и разные корни современного языка).

Рассмотрим параллели в индоевропейских языках, а также в финно-угорских, где заимствования консервируются (либо, по ностратической гипотезе, существуют когнаты). Для древнегреческого это будет слово ***ἄρκτος*** (арктос, отсюда же - имя и персонаж [Аркад](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B4)), армянское [***arǰer***], множество [(прото)иранских когнатов](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-Iranian/Hr%CC%A5t%C4%89%C3%A1s) с начальным согласным х. Для древнегреческих диалектов положение придыхательного х перед согласными было факультативно.

В финно-угорских языках это ***ош*** на коми (языке, сохранившем изрядную долю значений и заимствований из древнерусских слов), прибалтийские ***karhu*** (более близкое к индоевропейской форме по причине финнно-славянских соответствий), ***ohto*** и ***otso***. У коми (а также множества палеосибирских народов) существовал культ солнечного медведя. Вероятно, у славян медведь (в отличие от волка) также был солнечным божеством.

Исходя из параллелей с финно-угорскими заимствованиями (когнатами?), индо-иранскими и древнегреческим, армянским языками, а также - [исключения для закона R.U.K.I. в славянских языках](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruki_sound_law), ***в начале слова должен быть звук х***.

Далее - звук, средний между а и о (шва).

Затем - эр (из протоевропейского ретрофлексивного д), эс (как соответствие прибалтийско-финским в когнатах и(ли) заимстованиях из предков балто-славяно-германских языков - да, есть факты, позволяющие постулировать родство финно-угорских и индоевропейских наречий), плюс-минус ещё шва.

В итоге получаем слово [Хър(ъ)съ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%81) - вряд ли имя божества было заимствовано из индоиранского пантеона. Когнаты: [хорт](http://izbakurnog.historic.ru/enc/item/f00/s19/a001984.shtml) (вспомним метонимию слова  "бирюк"), [Хортица](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0) (топоним с неопределёной этимологией). Возможный когнат (как исключение из закона Педерсена) - фамилия Щорс.

Comment: arjer - это множественное число, arj - по-армянски медведь

Comment: arǰer - это, насколько я помню, не множественное число, а притяжательная форма, но какое отношение это имеет к сути вопроса?

Comment: Это не притяжательное, это множественное число, а отношение имеет такое, что перечисляя когнаты принято их в единообразной форме перечислять.

Comment: Значит, случилась маленькая революция в презентации когнатов.